# send a get request in acrobat javascript

Tags: javascript, http, adobe, get, acrobat

I've been looking within the acrobat documentation for a way to do a simple GET request and collect the response. There is a SOAP interface that requires a WSDL, etc, but I think that's a bit overkill for what I'm trying to achieve. Does anyone know of a function  I could use to do a simple GET request?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Does Acrobat's JS engine support XMLHttpRequest? THat'd let you make any kind of http request you'd want, including get.

Comment: This adobe.com site says otherwise unfortunately: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/286642

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `Net.HTTP`: http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/JS_API_AcroJS.88.914.html

Comment: That link you sent doesn't seem to be working under firefox 4

Comment: Use a different browser or this PDF (page 548): http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Comment: Apparently this only works in acrobat pro - are there any non-pro solutions I could use?

Comment: It reads like that you need Acrobat 9.1. Are you talking about Acrobat Reader, or how is it not working?

Comment: The product comparison lists all the interesting features as Acrobat X Pro: http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/matrix.html - guess you need to contact support to find out more.

Comment: Thanks Till, I'll call them and reply here.